# How to make text wrap when resizing in an inline div without the div moving onto a new line first?

Tags: html, css, text, resize

I'm trying to layout a comments board for a site I'm doing and am having some trouble with resizing.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kvDr3/2

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.post {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.number {
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.message {
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  color: black;
}

.info {
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="post">
      <div class="number">1.</div>
      <div class="message">
        <div class="title">Bla bla bla bla blaaaaaaaa bla bla bla sheep bla chair bla bla bla foo bla bla bla </div>
        <div class="info">Post by JoshuaESummers</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
      <div class="number">2.</div>
      <div class="message">
        <div class="title">Bla bla bla bla blaaaaaaaa </div>
        <div class="info">Post by JoshuaESummers</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

I want to keep the space between my 'number' and 'message' constant even when the page resizes. I'm not sure how JSFiddle loads - but when the Results tab is made wide enough the there is space to the right of the number on both comments.

When the page is made smaller the top div jumps down a line before the text starts to wrap - whilst leaving the shorter post in it's proper place - and this all looks rather ugly! I don't want to use tables.

Comment: Do `display:inline` instead of `block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kvDr3/7

```
.post {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.number {
    float: left;
}
.title, .info {
    white-space: normal;
    margin-right: 60px;
}
```

You probably also want to put a min-width or overflow-hidden on .container. Eventually stuff pushes out as you shrink it.